# Как сделать анимацию чтобы блок наоборот открывался через height: 'toggle' в длине 250px?

Tags: jquery, css

```js
$(function(){
 $('.arrow').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({marginTop: '25px'},200);
     $(this).animate({
       width: '150px',
        height: 'toggle'
        });
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  margin: auto;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="arrow"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, не очень понятно, что вы хотите в итоге получить.
Чтобы toggle сработал в обратном порядке, вам нужно установить элементу нулевую высоту, а в стилях желаемую. Но тогда и нажимать будет не на что, т.к. элемент с нулевой высотой будет невидим.

Я сделал иначе, хотя это скорей всего не то, что вам нужно. Но из вопроса не очень понятен желаемый результат.
Но может хоть натолкнет на идеи.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    $('.arrow1').toggleClass('active');
  });

  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('disabled', true);
    $('.arrow2').addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.arrow {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 150px;
  height: 0;
  background: #000;
  top: 25px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.arrow.active {
  top: 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn1">Вкл/Выкл</button> <button id="btn2">Вкл</button>

<div class="arrow arrow1"></div>
<br>
<div class="arrow arrow2"></div>
```